# Merging a sum by reference with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have two `data.table`, `dt_a` and `dt_b` defined as below.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(20201111L)

dt_a <- data.table(
  foo = c("a", "b", "c")
)

dt_b <- data.table(
  bar = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10L, replace=TRUE),
  value = runif(10L)
)

dt_b[]
##      bar     value
##   1:   c 0.4904536
##   2:   c 0.9067509
##   3:   b 0.1831664
##   4:   c 0.0203943
##   5:   c 0.8707686
##   6:   a 0.4224133
##   7:   a 0.6025349
##   8:   b 0.4916672
##   9:   a 0.4566726
##  10:   b 0.8841110
```

I want to left join `dt_b` on `dt_a` by reference, summing over the multiple match. A way to do so would be to first create a summary of `dt_b` (thus solving the multiple match issue) and merge if afterwards.

```
dt_b_summary <- dt_b[, .(value=sum(value)), bar]
dt_a[dt_b_summary, value_good:=value, on=c(foo="bar")]
dt_a[]
##     foo value_good
##  1:   a   1.481621
##  2:   b   1.558945
##  3:   c   2.288367
```

However, this will allow memory to the object `dt_b_summary`, which is inefficient.

I would like to have the same result by directly joining on `dt_b` and summing multiple match. I'm looking for something like below, but that won't work.

```
dt_a[dt_b, value_bad:=sum(value), on=c(foo="bar")]
dt_a[]
##     foo value_good value_bad
##  1:   a   1.481621  5.328933
##  2:   b   1.558945  5.328933
##  3:   c   2.288367  5.328933
```

Anyone knows if there is something possible?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The exact second code bloc, but without having to create `dt_b_summary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `.EACHI` with `by`

```
library(data.table)
dt_b[dt_a, .(value = sum(value)), on = .(bar = foo), by = .EACHI]
#   bar    value
#1:   a 1.481621
#2:   b 1.558945
#3:   c 2.288367
```

---

If we want to update the original object 'dt_a'

```
dt_a[, value := dt_b[.SD,  sum(value), on = .(bar = foo), by = .EACHI]$V1]
dt_a
#   foo    value
#1:   a 1.481621
#2:   b 1.558945
#3:   c 2.288367
```

---

For multiple columns

```
dt_b$value1 <- dt_b$value
nm1 <- c('value', 'value1')
dt_a[, (nm1) := dt_b[.SD, lapply(.SD, sum), 
       on = .(bar = foo), by = .EACHI][, .SD, .SDcols = nm1]]
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that won't left join it on `dt_a` by reference.

Comment: What's the `.SD` for in this situation?

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier It is the `Subset of Data.table` from `dt_a` Because we are using the `dt_b` inside the `dt_a` for which `.SD` is from `dt_a`

Comment: I get it, I was confused, I thought `.SD` was defined within `dt_b`, which is false since `.SD` is only defined in `j`, thus within `dt_a` here

Comment: The exact output of my 2nd code bloc using the `dt_b_summary` intermediary object. The thing is I have numerous columns to copy by reference, not a single one... That would get ugly on the syntax, but could work I guess

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier For multiple columns i would have `nm1 <- yourcolumnvectorofnames; dt_a[, (nm1) := dt_b[.SD, lapply(.SD, sum), on = .(bar = foo), .SDcols = nm1, by = .EACHI]$V1]`

Comment: Yep, that would work. I'm just still trying to get why we perform a left join on `dt_b` to make another left join on `dt_a` after. By brain's still processing.

Comment: The following would make more sense for me still it has a single left join performed:
`cols <- "value"; dt_a[dt_b[, lapply(.SD, sum), bar, .SDcols=cols], (cols):=mget(cols), on=c(foo="bar")]`

Comment: Please don't get mad! I just try to understand what's going on here!

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier I am not getting mad.  I just want to utilize my time on something which gives some return.  that is all.  No hard feelings

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier I try to answer your example as it is showed.  Then you asked a different example and for that also I tried to give my opinion.  Sorry, it is taking a bit of time from me.  Thank you for the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224446/discussion-between-j-p-le-cavalier-and-akrun).